# ShareKit posting an URL to Facebook

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sharekit

I'm using ShareKIt (the latest version, from http://www.getsharekit.com/) and I'm trying to post a link to facebook.  When I do, the message textfield is empty. Twitter and Email work fine. I tried sharing plain text, and it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
NSURL *shareURL=[NSURL URLWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"APP_STORE_LINK", nil)];
NSString *urlText=NSLocalizedString(@"SHARE_LINK_TEXT", nil);
SHKItem *shareItem=[SHKItem URL:shareURL title:urlText];
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet=[SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:shareItem];
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Comment: The version on http://www.getsharekit.com/ was really, really old last time I checked! I don't think the site is being maintained. Look for it on GitHub instead.

Comment: https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit downloaded, still same issue.

Comment: That repository doesn't seem to have been edited in the past year. This seems more recent: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

Comment: This one doesn't work at all. Can't authorize on twitter, facebook opens in safari, and then shows error.

Answer (score 0):

The facebook api has been updated since sharekit was last updated.  That might explain the problem.

However, when Facebook updated their API, they made it VERY easy to implement.  Check out this tutorial and see if you can just do it manually.

[Facebook for developers - sample app tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)